# Spotfire email automation and filter

Tags: email, filter, automation, ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to email the same report visualizations to over a dozen managers, but want the visualizations to get filtered by a single manager before being emailed to that individual. How can I create a job script to do this? I haven't scripted or created automation jobs in Spotfire and am unsure where the entry point for this would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link : [How to Use Automation Services](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire_autsvcs/10.2.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_autsvcs_10.2.0_UserGuide/GUID-7215B7FA-321D-4C1B-A1AD-4EFD8C1C8CDE.html). The easiest is to use the automation service builder and when opening a file use the [Configuration Block](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/create-configuration-block-tibco-spotfire) to effect the filtering.